# Twilio video conference application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twilio

We are trying to create a video conference application using [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/video) javascript SDK and rails in back end. We need to allow user to force mute other participant in the conversation. We have checked twilio docs and tried some methods from it and none of them helped. Can some one suggest a way to do the same?

Note: We use actioncable in our application and have access to all participants in the conversation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you started with the suggestions here?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/tracks#mute-one

You can further explore the docs and [available methods here](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.9/docs/AudioTrack.html).

Since you don't mention anything specific that you've tried, I'll suggest you start with the `disabled` method for the `AudioTrack`. I'm happy to update my answer if you provide some more context or code snippet around what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. We have tried disabling the audiotrack of remote participant's media and tried `muted` option in participant's media stream.

Please correct me, if I'm wrong. I think [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/tracks#mute-one) is used to mute the local media that is being sent to the conversation. 

We want to specifically force mute a remote participants.

Scenario Explained: Lets say there are 3 participants in conversation(P1, P2 and P3). Our goal is to allow P1 mute the P2 and P3 from P1's side.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement was solved using actioncable in following manner:
Lets say there are three participants(p1, p2 & p3) in channel.

1. Participant(p1) clicks on `force mute` on participant(p2), which in turns sends a message across the channel using actioncable.
2. On participant(p2) side, process the message and mute media if message is address to p2.
3. This message also notifies the p3 that p2 is muted.

Thanks